# Moving a Wordpress website from one server to another

Tags: server

Can I do this with just the database and the themes folder?

Comment: Please be more specific. Have you read the relevant parts of the Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Check out [this article from the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress). If you will be using a new domain the chapter is named **Changing Your Domain Name and URLs**; if you won't use a new domain name use **Keeping Your Domain Name and URLs**.

Edit: You must use the entire wp-content folder and not only the themes folder. If you use only the themes folder you will lose the files in the Media Library.

Answer (score 1):

Like Denish said, moving database and theme folder is not enough. You have to move complete wp-content folder since you might not want to lose all the plugins that you have currently.
And if you are changing the domain name this thread (www.wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-copy-wordpress-site-to-local-test-server) might help you to move easily. You just have to replace http://localhost/testsite with your new domain as http://newdomainname.com

Good luck with the moving

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is via a backup plugin which understands + correctly handles WordPress serialized data.

I tend to use Duplicator, because...

1) I can set it to use mysqldump, which is faster than php for large tables

2) When I open a support ticket with a problem, the developer add fixes fast.

3) When I open a support ticket with an enhancement request, so far these have been honored + added in an update eventually.

4) Duplicator just works. Every time.

Note: I don't work for Duplicator Development. I just use their code.